# SO shows popover ad for teams that covers content

Tags: support, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-for-teams, site-ads

I keep seeing this pop-over appearing on the site which covers up the content. I have probably dismissed it at least a hundred times over the last few months. This is a really bad usability anti-pattern, and not the kind of behaviour I expect from SO. Is popover ads the future of SO?

[image: teams popover]

Comment: It’s entirely possible to complain/ask about this issue reasonably and without all the hyperbole.

Comment: that's... pretty interesting. I've never seen such a popup, is it because i have the sticky nav and left nav disabled? In either case, adblock will fix it.

Comment: @yivi I think it's a pretty reasonable reaction to having a piece of code interrupt you constantly about something you won't ever need.

Answer (score 15):

So, first things first:

- Thanks for reporting this! You definitely shouldn't have to be dismissing anything like this *multiple times*, and for now I'm treating that as a bug - more in a bit.
- The popup is turned off now, for everyone. You shouldn't see it anymore, at least not until we get this figured out. We're testing some other things anyway, which will hopefully be less problematic.

Now... This is how that little ad is *supposed to* work:

1. It shows up the third time you request a page from SO
2. Until you dismiss it, it keeps showing up
3. When you dismiss it, it sets a cookie (named `notice-ctt`). If you're logged in, it *also* sets a flag on your account.
4. **If either the cookie or the flag is set, it's never shown again.**

Clearly if you've been dismissing this thing for months, that isn't quite working out... So I started digging through the logs earlier today to try to figure out why. And... Here's where it got weird: you appear to have hit various pages on Stack Overflow and a few other SE sites over the course of the day, but none recognized you as logged in until you came here to meta - *as soon as you hit meta, the system recognized your account!*

So I have a couple of theories as to why this happened - but I can't confirm either. If one of 'em sounds right, please let me know; if *neither* of them sounds right, then we might have a bug somewhere.

1. You're using Chrome's Incognito Mode (or similar) to browse SO, but visited meta normally.
2. Your account was somehow in a state where you were *not* logged in on any site but Meta SO. This... should not happen.

I'd greatly appreciate any additional info you can provide here; hopefully together we can figure out what happened.

Comment: #1 is correct, mostly. I'm a full stack developer so I often start clean with incognito or one of about 10 user profiles for various testing purposes. When I need to look something up, I will just use any browser window that happens to be open, start a new tab and often wind up on SO. I used to get the popup 5x a day, it has been reduced a lot lately, so that I only see it 2-3 times a week now. You must have been showing it on the first hit when you started doing this cover-the-question thing last year, and now I only see it when I use that session 3x before closing it.

Comment: I don't really care about the ad (as long as it doesn't blink or flash). I care that it covers up part of the content. There's space on the left, why not keep the whole ad box on the left?

Comment: That's what you get for eating all those cookies ;)

Comment: We've replaced it with a dismissable banner *below* answers on some question pages, @alice. Should be considerably less annoying even if the dismiss doesn't stick.

Comment: Thanks, that is cool... you know I was searching for others complaining about the same thing 6 months ago when it was popping up more often, and I couldn't figure out why nobody else was screaming about it. I'm sure I'm not the only one who does this.

Comment: If you block third party cookies you don't automatically get logged in on other SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

This should now be resolved. Please let us know if you're still experiencing the issue.